# Relation between Fourier transforms and coherence of signals

Tags: image-processing, frequency, spectral-analysis, fourier-transform

**My overall aim is to compare the edges of two images by comparing their Fourier Transforms (FFT) and to calculate one number as a key performance indicator that describes how much they are similar to each other.**

My first step was to convert the image into grayscale and fill an array with the last pixel row. The content of the array can be treated as a signal with numbers between 0 and 255.

example with size=437:

'''
[193 190 186 181 175 181 177 170 164 159 158 159 160 179 175 172 164 153
152 151 142 123 169 165 166 170 171 168 166 167 170 173 174 175 166 167
... 69  98  52  88  83  52]
'''

1. Is it right that when two FFTs are compared, the coherence should be used as a statistical instrument?
2. The [coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Definition) is calculated by dividing the cross-spectral density between the two signals x and y by the product of their auto-spectral density. The [Wiener–Khinchin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem) states that the power spectral density of a stationary random process is the FFT of the corresponding autocorrelation function. So by applying the coherence function onto my signal arrays (containing the grayscale pixel information), I automatically apply a FFT onto my signal?

I will be thankful for answers to these questions!

Comment: You might have better luck talking to people who do signal processing, such as dsp.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: [Asked on dsp.SE already](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/75663/235), and so perhaps this question should be closed here.

Comment: Sadly nobody answered my questions yet, so I tried to increase the possibility of a fast answer by asking in other forums as well. So I would please you not to close my question yet as long as I do not have a satisfying answer.